# Gmail won't forward mail sent to myself

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-forwarding, domain

I own a dedicated server with a domain, we'll say **foobar.com**. I use Google Apps to manage my email SMTP servers.

Now I don't check two Gmail inboxes. I have my own personal one, and then I have **foobar.com**'s inbox from Google Apps. Naturally the easiest thing to do is just have all **foobar**'s emails forwarded to my personal one. So then I am only checking one inbox. This is all fine and dandy.

I use MSMTP that with a wrapper that uses `/etc/aliases`. I have it set so any mail attempting to go to root (things from cron, etc) will go to **support@foobar.com**.

So when Google App's (foobar.com) gets an email from the email I have setup with it (support@foobar.com), it automatically doesn't forward the message. This is a "feature" to Gmail/Google Apps I suppose.

How do I get around it, workarounds, etc.?

I could just have my alias set to my personal email but I wanted a place to have all foobar related emails archived in one place (Google Apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Feburary 16th, 2011

Emails to root seem to start forwarding to my personal email. I did not change anything on my part so I feel it was either a bug on google's system or apart of the new changes they are doing to Google Apps. This problem is no more.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and took me days to figure out.

It is related to your server setting, not Google Apps. I assume your server is running cPanel.

1. log in cPanel account of the account (domain)
2. Click "MX Entry" under "Mail"
3. Select your domain from the drop down list
4. Select "Remote Mail Exchanger" under "Email Routing"
5. Click "Change" button and you are done.

If you do not set email routing to "remote mail exchanger", the email will be delivered locally when sent from the server, thus you don't get the emails in Google Apps (external mail server).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope I do not have cPanel

Comment: I use cPanel as example. Try to check your email routing setting on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Create the user "support" in your Google Apps admin page, and then log into that user directly.  From the user's settings page, you should be able to set forwarding options as normal, and have that forward to your main email address, and set up a filter based on the To: field (e.g. if To:support@foobar.com - apply label "Support")

Comment: I know. I do that currently. Gmail refuses to forward emails that are sent to itself. I set all emails to support@foobar.com to forward to my personal email.  If I email from: support@foobar.com to: support@foobar.com ...it never forwards

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but can you setup an alias on your own account like bhare+foobar@personal.com, forward the support@foobar.com to that, and then filter on your personal side?